# Unable to extract Response Code from the sampler despite using correct regular expression in regular expression extractor. Why?

Tags: jmeter, http-response-codes

I'm new to Jmeter, trying to extract response code from the http request, for testing purpose I've tried to load google.com. I've used regular expression extractor but unable to understand why response code is not getting extracted despite there being response code=200 which I've validated through response assertion for response code?
[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotation marks around your regular expression, [HTTP Response Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is a **number**, nothing else.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Thanks, so for other than numeric data, quotes will be required, right?

Comment: Not necesserily. It mainly depends on the nature of data you will be extracting.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the Regular expression as

> Response code:(\d+)

,you will get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks, when do we add quotes in regular expression?

Comment: We need to use quotes when the value to be captured is within quotes.